# RKHS rough definition

Tags: hilbert-spaces, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space) provides an intuitive explanation of RKHS as a Hilbert space of functions where point evaluation is a continuous linear functional:

> Roughly speaking...if two functions $f$ and $g$ in the RKHS are close
>   in norm, i.e., $\|f-g\|$ is small, then $f$ and $g$ are also pointwise
>   close, i.e., $|f(x)-g(x)|$ is small for all $x$. The reverse need not
>   be true.

I see the first statement holds because of the continuity/boundedness of pointwise evaluation. Why does the reverse not necessarily hold -- what's a simple example I should be thinking of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$, take $g=0$, and $$f_m(n)=\begin{cases} 1/\sqrt{m},&\ n\leq m\\ \ \\ 0,&\ n>m\end{cases}$$
Then, for each $n$, we have $\|f_m(n)-g(n)\|\leq1/\sqrt m$, while 
$$
\|f_m-g\|_2=1
$$
for all $m$. That is, the sequence $f_m$ converges uniformly to zero, but in the two-norm it remains a fixed distance from the origin.

Comment: Thanks -- I'm not familiar with $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$, how is the $\ell^2$ norm defined here?

Comment: It's the space of square summable sequences. $$\ell^2(\mathbb N)=\{f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb C:\ \sum_n|f(n)|^2<\infty\},$$ with $$\|f\|=\left(\sum_n|f(n)|^2\right)^{1/2}.$$ It looks to me that you need to learn a bit about Hilbert spaces. The space $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ is the quintessential Hilbert space.

Answer (score 0):

A continuous example to complement Martin's one. Take the Brownian motion RKHS over $[0,1]$, i.e., the set of functions $f$ over $[0,1]$ with $||f||=\sqrt{\int f'(x)^2dx}$. Let $g=0$ and 
$$  f_n(x)=\frac{\sqrt{2} }{n\pi}\sin (n\pi x). $$
Then, for each $x$, we have $|f_n(x)-g(x)|\leq 1/\frac{\sqrt{2} }{n\pi}$, while 
$$
\|f_n-g\|_2=1
$$
for all $n$.